# Facebook Connect for the website - database connection and logic

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am trying to let the users login to my website using their Facebook account. I have tried reading some information related to the process from Facebook developers (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) page - while the process and the logic sort of make sense, I am still lost regarding the big picture.

How does 'Facebook connect' link to my existing database of users and their attributes. Say there is a user called John Walker, who is a registered user (login: jwalker pass:1234 account balance:$10). When he will come to the website, and try to login using Facebook login, how would it know where to direct him? In other words, how will Facebook know that it is the right John Walker, and he should be sent to his user page?

I am sorry if this question is trivial, but I just can't think it though myself. Thanks for your help in advance!

Zachary

Answer (score 0):

Well Zachary, you have a little bit misconception regarding to facebook connect. When a user clicks on facebook connect button placed on your site, facebook doesn't go to your database to authenticate the user. He authenticates the user in his database that whether the current user is having a facebook account or not... If he/she is having account then facebook issues an access token to you for that particular user by loging him to facebook. Then its now your responsibility to login that user in your system and putting his information to your database. Let me explain more and see the following code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({appId: "Your APP ID",
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        // This is the place where you get control when user is login to facebook
                // At this point you can redirect the user to a page where you can put the facebook returned information to database and login him into your system

      } else {

        }
    }); 
    FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {

    window.location.reload();
      });
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function(response) {


    self.location.href="http://www.iranibash.com/logout.php";
      });
     };
   (function() {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
  }());
   </script>
```

Now you can use the information about user that facebook returns you after successfull login. You can have that information in a $cookie. I think you can understand from this information?